# Pass variable to sqldf function in R? R session aborted

Tags: r, variables, sqldf

I am having a problem doing this. This code works fine, but I would like to pass `t1.FIELD1` as a variable.

```
sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT  t1.ID as ID, t2.ID as bdev
FROM V_LINK AS t1
INNER JOIN V_LINK AS t2
ON (t1.FIELD1 = t2.FIELD2)
WHERE t1.ID <> t2.ID")
```

I have tried using:
`x <- 1`

```
sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT  t1.ID as ID, t2.ID as bdev
FROM V_LINK AS t1
INNER JOIN V_LINK AS t2
ON (sprintf("t%s.Fields%s",x,x) = t2.FIELD2)
WHERE t1.ID <> t2.ID")
```

When I do this I get a pop up saying "R session aborted. R encountered a fatal error"

Any idea why this is happened and what any alternative might be?

Thank you!

Comment: The code you've posted is invalid. R should give you an error but it won't abort. That being said, **you must not use `sprintf` with SQL**. Doing so is a major red flag, because it introduces security holes via [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You *must* use parametrised queries instead. (I realise that sqldf isn't accessing an actual database, but it's still an incredibly bad habit that should never be accepted into code.)

Comment: (As a more general comment, I would recommend using dplyr and tidyr instead of sqldf if you're just starting out in R; the approach taken by sqldf has fundamental limitations. I'd claim that the clear majority of data analysis experts wouldn't recommend using sqldf.)

Comment: If you are creating public facing data processing systems then SQL injection could be a problem but if you are performing self contained  scientific and statistical calculations which is mostly what R is used for SQL injection as a security issue is not something that needs to be considered.  Except in special situations I wouldn't recommend following the advice in the comments above.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck You're right on purely technical grounds but it's incredibly poor advice for a beginner on didactic grounds. (SQL) injections are *the* single most common source of security vulnerabilities, and training oneself to spot and avoid them is crucial. The easiest way of avoiding this is to develop a subconscious "pattern matching" against any kind of potential SQL injection situation. As a consequence I believe that your comment (to ignore my advice) is actively harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Since the example in the question cannot be run as V_LINK is missing we illustrate this with a different example.  Here mtcars is a built in data frame and x contains a string which we want to insert into the sql statement template shown.

```
library(sqldf)

x <- "t1.cyl"
fn$sqldf("select * from mtcars as t1 
  where $x < t1.gear")
```

giving:

```
   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
1 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.7  0  1    5    2
2 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```